# The Run Destination is not valid Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7

I am using `Xcode 5` and when I try to run my app on `iOS 6` simulator I am getting the following error.

```
 The scheme 'Appname' contains no buildables that can be built for the 
`SDKs` supported by the run destination iPhone Retina (4-inch). Make sure your 
targets all specify `SDKs` that are supported by this version of `Xcode`.
```

Base `SDK` is set to `iOS SDK 7.0`.
iOS deployment target is set to `iOS 6.0`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For me, select the Project  from the Project Navigator and then select the target -> go build settings and change the iOS Deployment Target.
That's worked for me.Let me know if you still facing issue.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are trying to run app on the iPhone while your application allows you only iPad platform. [image]

Answer (score 3):

#### Try this simple one:

```
Target 
   '---> General 
             '---> Deployment Info  
                          '---> Deployment Target 
                                     '---> Choose Version (Better lower version)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  Autocreating schemes (Scheme > Manage schemes > Autocreate schemes) to see if this solves your issue.

Also make sure that your build settings are correct. They should look like the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If its an Apple Watch app:
Needed to install latest xcode to have watchkit.
(I got the package from github.)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same issues, however after restarting My (Xcode 9.2) IDE the issue disappeared!